# IIS Authentication Working in Test Environment\Site on Local Web Host, Fails when Accessing from Remote System on Same Domain

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Hoping to find a resolution to an issue I am experiencing.

We have a site that our developer has created which is a file upload utility. Back end access to an SQL Server Database.

In my IIS test environment (the web server itself), I am able to browse to the site, create folders and upload files. The "file owner" after upload shows as the authenticated user over the web session. This is for versioning control and file traceability. Impersonation appears to be functioning as the authentication token is passed from the users Windows session over the browser. No authentication box needed.

If I use my laptop and access the same site's URL, I am prompted for authentication. I enter my domain credentials and they are not accepted. This process repeats till it throws an error indicating that:

> Access to the path '\domain\Folder\Folder' is denied

I have confirmed that access to the directory over Windows File Explorer works using the same authenticated user (me) at \servername\Folder\Folder. I am able to manually create and upload files through this share.

- IIS version is 8.5
- Using ASP.net impersonation.
- IIS Authentication settings are as follows:

  - `Anonymous Authentication = enabled, specific user=IUSR
  - ASP.NET Impersonation=enabled, Authenticated user
  - Basic, Digest, Forms=disabled
  - Windows Authentication=enabled, providers=1.NTLM, 2.Negotiate, Extended
  - Protections=Accept, Kernel-mode authentication=enabled`

Web.config file contains these entries:

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
     <authorization>
         <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
 <authentication>
     <authentication mode="Windows">
 </authentication>
     <identity impersonation="true" />
</system.web>
```

IIS log file shows this after authentication failure:

> 2020-02-03 20:54:56 WebServerIP GET / - 80 domain\username ClientLocalIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:72.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/72.0 - 401 0 0 770

To me that entry indicates a permissions error but I have confirmed I have access to the directory.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An IIS level authentication/permission issue should not record 401.0 in IIS log files. Please enable failed request tracing to learn more.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li, I will do that and report back my findings.

Comment: Have you tried to set domain for your external access and register SPN for that domain?

Comment: Hi Jokies Ding. This is an internal application only. Any users external are still domain users and have access through Microsoft Remote App services.

I believe this may be related to the infamous Kerberos Double Hop, but getting away from that and registering SPN's. I'm afraid I don't have much experience with that and am unsure how to proceed. I've read about setting SPN's but am unsure if I need to do that on the file server or on the web server. Please note that the SQL Database is hosted on the IIS server as well, so from my understanding SPN is not required on the web server?

Comment: @MatthewPereira Do you have WebDav installed? Recently, I notice that webdav will cause 401.0 error.